# Stanford GloVe's lack of punctuation?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I understand that [GloVe](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) trains vectors by noticing what frequently co-occurs, etc, but how come commas and periods are not included? For anything NLP, it seems like it would be an important feature to have a vector representation. I realize that something like (king - man = queen) would make no sense with (word - , = ?), but is there a way to represent punctuation marks and Numbers?

Is there a pre-made data set that includes such things? Would this even work?

I tried training GloVe with my own data set, but I ran into a problem with separating the punctuation (with a blank space) between words, etc.

Answer (score 4):

pre-trained  GloVe vectors do have punctuation, what makes you think they don't? At least Wikipedia 2014 + Gigaword 5 (6B tokens) set from http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/ have embeddings for "," ".", "-" and other included, just download these word vectors, and verify it yourseld, they are in plain text format, so its easy to do.

Comment: Ah, okay, I was using the text8 default training set

Comment: GloVe includes the word o'clock and C'mon but not don't, we're, I'm etc.

They do not document how you should tokenize your text to match their pre-trained models. Same with Word2Vec 
:-(

Comment: Correction, GloVe pre-trained models "lowercase each corpus and tokenize it with the Stanford tokenizer". I found that tokenizer to perform slowly and you have to install Java to use it. I then tried nltk.tokenize.treebank.TreebankWordTokenizer. Stanford's tokenizer is based off the Penn Treebank tokenizer. Based on looking at the two outputs, I consider the NLTK Treebank to be "close enough for jazz" and use it rather than wait for the Stanford one to finish its task.

Comment: Meanwhile, after reading the Word2Vec source code, I realized they did not bother to describe how the words were tokenized. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I have worked a bit with the word vectors used by Senna, and I am looking at the vocab list.

http://ml.nec-labs.com/senna/

I definitely see entries for punctuation.

A trick for handling numbers is to replace every digit with 0, and then learn a distribution for each pattern.  For instance 1999 is mapped to 0000, 01-01-2015 is mapped to 00-00-0000, etc...

Senna has entries for these patterns like 0000, etc...

I will look over GloVe and try to update this answer soon...

Answer (score 0):

It is totally ok and also common to also handle punctuation as single tokens for word vector generation. Also see for example word2vec papers. I assume that the prebuilt word2vec datasets have punctuations. And i'm sure the prebuilt glove vectors have also punctuations.

The are a lot of tokenizers separating the punctuations as seperate word. One I know for sure is the ARK Tweet Tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used such a conversition for numbers and punctiotions. It is not a good way but slightly can be useful.

for numbers I convert all numbers to `"NUM"`.
**ex:**  `178 = "NUM"`  or `654 = "NUM"`

for punctiotions I convert them to "PUNC".
**ex:** `apple, orange, banana = apple "PUNC" orange "PUNC" banana`

this is not a good solution but works someway.